# Solidity ERC20 Contract with UTF-8 Decoded Characters

Tags: solidity, binance, erc20, openzeppelin, hardhat

I need to write a contract that uses verbiage from a latin based language. Which takes special characters such as `é, ç, ã, ô` etc....

I'm using Hard hat to write it.

I've found an example here, also using open Zeppelin:

[Example that works](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd15db6e8203fb3f9ce70714b306a1a2b03ebfe45#code)

[image]

When trying to write something similar in my contract I get an error: `Invalid character in string.`

```js
    contract Ouro is ERC20, Ownable {

    string public constant tokenMinuta = "Céu, Carraço"; // "Céu, Carraço" is the Problem to solve here

    constructor() ERC20("Ouro", "ORO") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000000000 * 10**decimals());
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

}
```

I then added UTF-8-encoded to those caracters with hopes that would compile correctly on either BSCScan or EtherScan:

i.e. `string public constant tokenMinuta = "C\xC3\xA9u, Carra\xC3\xA7o";`

The above compiles as it should in my terminal see here:
[image]

However it does not work when I add the source code to BSCScan or EtherScan.

[Special Character not compiled on a human readable way](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x0C2cF99Fa25429B95C2916025997d91bdB0fEcE5#code)

See where I added the UTF-8 - My hope is that this would compile on a human readable way and not like these:

[image]

My question is: How can I write those **special characters** in the body of contract without getting compiling errors and therefore be able to verify that contract with **those characters on a humanly readable way**s on either BSCSan or EtherScan? To work **just like** the very first example I've provided above.

Answer (score 1):

What's the solc compiler version you're using? I am compiling with 0.5.16 and it works with UTF-8 letters in the source code.

Don't UTF-8-encoded these letters in the string, it won't be transpiled yet.

Comment: I'm using HardHat and `pragma solidity ^0.8.0;` 
I don't understand your second part, I should not use the UTF-8 on a string? That's where I need to solve the problem. I need those special characters